# FoxitReader as default pdf viewer

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I installed Foxit on Ubuntu 18.04 according to their ubuntu installation guide:
(https://help.foxitsoftware.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac-linux/en-us/2.4/Get_Started.html:  Extract the package you downloaded, double-click the executable file, and then follow the step-by-step instructions in the Installation Wizard to install Foxit Reader on your computer. )
I am able to launch it by double clicking on FoxitReader, but I can't make it my default pdf Viewer.

In Foxit, the option "Set to Default PDF Viewer" is never staying ticked, and I can't find Foxit while right clicking on a pdf and using "open with another application" or going to "Properties/open with".

It seems that my Ubuntu doesn't know that Foxit is installed.
What could I do to make it my default pdf viewer?
And the terminal doesn't recognize foxit or foxitreader as command.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please post details of the steps you took to install Foxit and the link to "their ubuntu installation guide on Ubuntu 18.04".

Comment: @DKBose  I edited the question to make appear the installation steps

Comment: I'm using Xfce so don't know the Gnome way. That's how I do on Xfce:- Right click on any PDF file. Go to "Open with">>"Open with other application". In the next Window select Foxit Reader and check the box for "Use as default for this kind of files". Press "Open".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mimeopen`. From `man mimeopen`

```
OPTIONS
   -d, --ask-default
       Let the user choose a new default program for given files.
```

Run the following in a terminal, it will show you the list of available applications. Just provide the number in front of your desired application.

```
$ mimeopen -d /path/to/anyfile.pdf
Please choose a default application for files of type application/pdf

    1) Document Viewer  (evince)
    2) Foxit Reader  (FoxitReader)
    3) LibreOffice Draw  (libreoffice-draw)
    4) Other...

use application # 2
```

This onwards FoxitReader will be your default pdf viewer.

Comment: I tried "mimeopen --ask" on a pdf file but Foxit Reader is not listed in the list of applications

Comment: Running the command AND removing advised apps eventually let me open pdf file from firefox in a native foxit window